# Forward traffic between 2 network interfaces in one Laptop

Tags: networking

[image]

I have an ethernet module (a sensor but communicating via ethernet: TCP/IP) connecting to my laptop (x1 carbon). An android device (Pixel XL) in USB tethering mode connecting to my Laptop.

IP of ethernet module: 192.168.0.12 (set by me) -> interface in Laptop: 192.168.0.111 (static) (set by me)

IP of a Pixel: 192.168.42.129 (default of the phone) -> interface in Laptop: 192.168.0.29 (static) (set by me)

Now I want to forward packet from Pixel to the ethernet module and vice versa (ping at first). How can I do it? Please instruct in detail because I do not have the network background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be on topic on https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/ ?

Comment: @Mawg - definitely not serverfault - that is for professionals in a professional environment.  superuser yes, possibly even unix.se depending on what operating systems are in play...

Comment: Thanks (and upvote) for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable routing on your laptop.
If it is Linux, you do not need any other software. Try in a root shell:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```